# Errors when trying to build iOS with cordova in Mavericks (10.9.1)

Tags: ios, cordova, build, platform

Days ago I built the application for Android, zero problems, but now, when I try to do the same for iOS (obviously not the same commands) I always receive an error.

I use the following command:

```
cordova platform add ios
```

And I get the following error:

```
Downloading cordova library for ios...
Download complete
Creating ios project...
Error: An error occured during creation of ios sub-project. 
  File "/Users/xxxxx/.cordova/lib/ios/cordova/3.3.0/bin/update_cordova_subproject", line 31
     print __doc__
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/platform.js:282:30
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:956:11)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)
```

I tried also with:

```
phonegap build ios
```

But I get the same error and I don't know how to fix it. I've been looking on the Internet and I found some guy with the same problem but nobody could help him.

I run the commands with sudo, that isn't the problem.

Comment: open the `update_cordova_subproject` with a text editor an show lines 30 to 33 to me pls. Maybe the python script has some errors

Comment: $ sudo npm update -g cordova run this.then build your project

Comment: @matthisb here you have the lines:    
   `def Usage():
      print __doc__
      sys.exit(1)`

@Sport that doesn't work, I try it yesterday.

Comment: @matthisb I tried to delete some possible spaces in that line but the code seems correct.

Comment: what happens if you delete this line: `print __doc__`

Comment: @matthisb now the script stops at line 96:
`File "/Users/xxxxx/.cordova/lib/ios/cordova/3.3.0/bin/update_cordova_subproject", line 96
    print line,
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax` I already checked that line, removed that comma but the error still happens in that line.

Comment: hm i have no idea. Sorry

Comment: @matthisb well, thanks. I'll try in another Mac with Snow Leopard...

Comment: Do you use Python 2.7 or 3 by default ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler I think I upgraded to Python 3. But I made a clean install of Mavericks and I didn't upgrade this time to Python 3 and now works well the build command for iOS.

Comment: Just saying this because in Python2 Print is a statement and in Python 3 it's a function. With Python3 I had to change the Shebang to use Python2.7 instead of Python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently got the same error.

My problem was that I'm using Python3 by default. `print` in Python2 is a statement wherease in Python3 it's a function.

`.cordova/lib/ios/cordova/3.3.0/bin/update_cordova_subproject` has a shebang that calls `/bin/python`.

I had to replace `#!/bin/python` with `#!/bin/python2.7` to use python2.7 on this script.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exactly same problem with you. However, the way replace "`#!/bin/python` with `#!/bin/python2.7`" doesn't work for me.

Inspired by the explanation of Matthieu Riegler, I change `print __doc__` to `print(__doc__)` in line 31 and `print line` to `print(line)` in line 97. Eventually, it works.